How to Create a generic Link for iOS App and Website Navigation?
I have a website and a corresponding iOS application. I want to implement a  link that allows users to navigate to my website in a browser if the app is not installed, or open the app if it is installed.
Currently, two separate links configured on a different ios app: one for the app and one for the browser. My goal is to set up a single, generic URL.
Is it possible to achieve this behavior from an app or website perspective? If so, what steps are involved in setting this up?
ios app is build with maui and website with angular
NB : I am using wild card app build profile , so I guess universal link will not work

Checkout the universal link implementaion.
https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

I am using wild card profile for app build

Your goal is to set a single URL, and when you enter that URL in your browser, jump to the app if the device has the app installed, and if it doesn't, jump to your web page, right?

yes that's correct

Is it possible to set an explicit App ID for your app?  Depending on your needs, the official explanation of Universal Link is exactly what you need.


Universal links are standard HTTP or HTTPS links, one URL works for
both your website and your app. If the user has not installed your
app, the system opens the URL in Safari, allowing your website to
handle it.

According to Apple's explanation of universal link, it perfectly meets your demand. However, the Maui document explains that when creating the project identifier, you need to check Associated Domains, which means that the project's bundled ID needs to use explicit App ID.
So as a workaround, it is recommended that you change the wildcard to explicit App ID, which requires you to create a new provisioning profile.
After solving this obstacle, using universal link can perfectly solve your problem, and you can refer to the Apple universal links to set it up
